# Reading JLD files

Tags: file, file-io, makefile, julia

I have encountered this problem when reading a JLD file. I have successfully created the file as follows:

```
using JLD, HDF5
    for i in 1:10
    file = jldopen("/MY PATH/mydata.jld", "w")
    write(file, "A", vector[i] for i in 10 )  
    close(file)
    end
```

but when I read the file using the following instructions:

```
file = jldopen("/My PATH/my_tree/mydata.jld", "r")
```

For this first instruction,it's executed correctly, but when I execute the following:

```
read(file, "A")
```

I got this error:

```
WARNING: type Base.Generator{Core.Int64,##1#2} not present in workspace; reconstructing
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching julia_type(::Void)
 in _julia_type(::ASCIIString) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/JLD.jl:966
 in julia_type(::ASCIIString) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/JLD.jl:32
 in jldatatype(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/jld_types.jl:672
 in reconstruct_type(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::ASCIIString) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/jld_types.jl:737
 in jldatatype(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/jld_types.jl:675
 in read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/JLD.jl:381
 in read(::JLD.JldFile, ::ASCIIString) at /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/JLD.jl:357
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:237
```

Comment: you're using 0.5, which might be a problem, as it is still in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector[i] for i in 10` creates a *generator*, which JLD happily writes to the file for you. You probably want an *array*, so wrap that expression in `collect`.